# I need to copy the content of text file into yaml file at particular line using shell or ansible scripting language

Tags: scripting

My text file similarly looks like below

ICAgICAidHlwZSI6ICJhY2NlcHQiCiAgICB9CiAgXSwKICAidHJhbnNwb3J0cyI6IHsKICAgICJkb2NrZXIiOiB7CiAgICAgICJpbWFnZS1yZWdpc3RyeS5vcGVuc2hpZnQtaW1hZ2UtcmVnaXN0cnkuc3ZjOjUwMDAvaW1hZ2Utc2lnbmluZyI6IFsKICAgICAgICB7CiAgICAgICAgICAidHlwZSI6ICJzaWduZWRCeSIsCiAgICAgICAgICAia2V5VHlwZSI6ICJHUEdLZXlzIiwKICAgICAgICAgICJrZXlQYXRoIjogIi9ldGMvcGtpL3NpZ24ta2V5L2tleSIKICAgICAgICB9CiAgICAgIF0KIC

and YAML file as below

apiVersion: machineconfiguration.openshift.io/v1
kind: MachineConfig
metadata:
labels:
machineconfiguration.openshift.io/role: worker
name: image-policy
spec:
config:
ignition:
config: {}
security:
tls: {}
timeouts: {}
version: 3.2.0
networkd: {}
passwd: {}
storage:
files:
- contents:
source: data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,**<<copy_text_here>>**

now I need to copy the content of the text file into the YAML file at the source parameter in place of **<<copy_text_here>>**.

any suggestions on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should do de trick, you load the content of the file with lookup. Then you find the string and replace it with the replace module

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: replace
      replace:
        path: subst.yml
        regexp: '<<copy_text_here>>'
        replace: "{{lookup('file', 'text.yml')}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this.
Your answer helped me to resolve the issue. Now, being able to copy the content.